# как с помощью JSOUP получить всех родителей заголовка

Tags: java, html, java-ee, jsoup

у меня есть хтмл документ

```
<HTML xmlns:OG="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:FB="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <style type="text/css"></style>
    <BODY>
        <DIV class="block0">
            <DIV class="pad0">
                <DIV class="fblock">
                    <DIV class="block61">
                        <DIV class="rpad">
                            <H1 class="title">Во Франции по подозрению в планировании теракта задержали двух девушек</H1>
                            <SPAN class="dt2">Понедельник, 26 сентября 2016, 16:08</SPAN>
                            <DIV class="text">
                                <P>Во французском городе Ницца по подозрению в планировании теракта были задержаны двое девушек.</P>
                                <P>Об этом сообщает <A href="https://www.afp.com">AFP</A>.</P>
                                <P>Девушки в возрасте 17 и 18 лет подозреваются в планировании террористического нападения под руководством французского джихадиста Рашида Кассима.</P>
                                <P>Подростки рассказали следователям, что они планировали нападение под влиянием Рашида Кассима, который сейчас находится в Сирии или Ираке, на территории, которая контролируется террористической организацией &quot;Исламское государство&quot;.</P>
                                <P>Рашид Кассим, по мнению следователей, играет роль подстрекателя или спонсора, фактически призывая потенциальных террористов к совершению джихада во Франции.</P>
                                <P>Стоит добавить, что во время обыска в помещениях, которые принадлежат задержанными, стражи порядка не нашли оружия.</P>
                                <P>Издание отмечает, что девушки живут в том же районе, что и <A href="/rus/news/2016/07/15/7052184/">Мохамед Лахуайедж-Бухлель, убивший 86 человек</A> в Ницце 14 июля.</P>
                                <P>Напомним, недавно французская <A href="/rus/news/2016/09/14/7054550/">полиция задержала подростка</A>, подозреваемого в подготовке теракта в Париже.</P>
                            </DIV>
                            <DIV class="btit4"><SPAN>ЧИТАЙ ТАКЖЕ</SPAN></DIV>
                        </DIV>
                    </DIV>
                </DIV>
            </DIV>
        </DIV>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

с помощью JSOUPa я хотел получить всех "родителей" заголовка

```
Element element = Jsoup.parse(html).getElementsByClass("title").parents().last();
System.out.println(element);
```

В консоли я получил тот же HTML документ. Но мне нужно получить только "родителей" заголовка. без лишних тегов например вот так:

```
<HTML xmlns:OG="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:FB="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
   <BODY>
      <DIV class="block0">
         <DIV class="pad0">
            <DIV class="fblock">
               <DIV class="block61">
                  <DIV class="rpad">
                     <H1 class="title">ЗАГОЛОВОК СТАТЬИ</H1>
                  </DIV>
               </DIV>
            </DIV>
         </DIV>
      </DIV>
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Что можно с этим сделать?

И еще вопрос: как найти заголовок тег заголовка есть он будет называться не "title" , а как то по другому на пример : "head_article". так как парсить HTML я буду с разных сайтов.

Comment: что значит `хотел получить всех "родителей" заголовка` ? можно как-то чуть более понятно сказать? хотите их в список положить или что?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  в конечном результате мне нужно получить вот это : <HTML xmlns:OG="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:FB="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
   <BODY>
      <DIV class="block0">
         <DIV class="pad0">
            <DIV class="fblock">
               <DIV class="block61">
                  <DIV class="rpad">
                     <H1 class="title">ЗАГОЛОВОК СТАТЬИ</H1>
                  </DIV>
               </DIV>
            </DIV>
         </DIV>
      </DIV>
   </BODY>
</HTML>

без лишних тегов и без контента

Comment: заголовок будет всегда первым в блоке `<DIV class="rpad">` ?

Comment: нет.
это будут разные сайты. Этот HTML  я взял для примера.

Comment: Ну тогда тут ничем не помочь, если html разный, если класс у заголовка разный, по каким критериям тогда вообще искать заголовок, если он может быть даже не в теге `h1` ? то есть вы хотите парсить заголовок не зная, где он может находиться в принципе. звучит бредово

Comment: @АлексейШиманский 
ну да согласен задача сложная.
но если делать это в рамках примера то что можно с этим сделать?

Comment: В рамках примера все просто. Однако это не будет иметь смысла в дальнейшем, раз нет критериев определения заголовка и прочих деталей

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Основываясь только на данном примере всё просто:

- берем элемент, в который входит заголовок
- заменяем его содержимое на html заголовка с текстом (первого потомка сего блока)

```
String html = "<HTML xmlns:OG=\"http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/\" xmlns:FB=\"http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml\">\n" +
        "    <style type=\"text/css\"></style>\n" +
        "    <BODY>\n" +
        "        <DIV class=\"block0\">\n" +
        "            <DIV class=\"pad0\">\n" +
        "                <DIV class=\"fblock\">\n" +
        "                    <DIV class=\"block61\">\n" +
        "                        <DIV class=\"rpad\">\n" +
        "                            <H1 class=\"title\">Во Франции по подозрению в планировании теракта задержали двух девушек</H1>\n" +
        "                            <SPAN class=\"dt2\">Понедельник, 26 сентября 2016, 16:08</SPAN>\n" +
        "                            <DIV class=\"text\">\n" +
        "                                <P>Во французском городе Ницца по подозрению в планировании теракта были задержаны двое девушек.</P>\n" +
        "                                <P>Об этом сообщает <A href=\"https://www.afp.com\">AFP</A>.</P>\n" +
        "                                <P>Девушки в возрасте 17 и 18 лет подозреваются в планировании террористического нападения под руководством французского джихадиста Рашида Кассима.</P>\n" +
        "                                <P>Подростки рассказали следователям, что они планировали нападение под влиянием Рашида Кассима, который сейчас находится в Сирии или Ираке, на территории, которая контролируется террористической организацией &quot;Исламское государство&quot;.</P>\n" +
        "                                <P>Рашид Кассим, по мнению следователей, играет роль подстрекателя или спонсора, фактически призывая потенциальных террористов к совершению джихада во Франции.</P>\n" +
        "                                <P>Стоит добавить, что во время обыска в помещениях, которые принадлежат задержанными, стражи порядка не нашли оружия.</P>\n" +
        "                                <P>Издание отмечает, что девушки живут в том же районе, что и <A href=\"/rus/news/2016/07/15/7052184/\">Мохамед Лахуайедж-Бухлель, убивший 86 человек</A> в Ницце 14 июля.</P>\n" +
        "                                <P>Напомним, недавно французская <A href=\"/rus/news/2016/09/14/7054550/\">полиция задержала подростка</A>, подозреваемого в подготовке теракта в Париже.</P>\n" +
        "                            </DIV>\n" +
        "                            <DIV class=\"btit4\"><SPAN>ЧИТАЙ ТАКЖЕ</SPAN></DIV>\n" +
        "                        </DIV>\n" +
        "                    </DIV>\n" +
        "                </DIV>\n" +
        "            </DIV>\n" +
        "        </DIV>\n" +
        "       <DIV class=\"block0\">\n" +
        "          <DIV class=\"pad0\">\n" +
        "                <DIV class=\"fblock\">\n" +
        "                    <DIV class=\"block61\">\n" +
        "                        <DIV class=\"rpad\">\n" +
        "                            <H1 class=\"title\">Во Фsdfsdfsfх девушек</H1>\n" +
        "                            <SPAN class=\"dt2\">Понедельник, 26 сентября 2016, 16:08</SPAN>\n" +
        "                            <DIV class=\"btit4\"><SPAN>ЧИТАЙ ТАКЖЕ</SPAN></DIV>\n" +
        "                        </DIV>\n" +
        "                    </DIV>\n" +
        "                </DIV>\n" +
        "            </DIV>\n" +
        "        </DIV>\n" +
        "    </BODY>\n" +
        "</HTML>";

// загрузка html 
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
// берем все элементы в который входит title 
Elements els = document.select(".rpad");
// пробегаясь по всем ним, меняем внутри html
// child(0) - как раз html заголовка 
for (Element el : els) {
    el.html(el.child(0).toString());
}

System.out.println(document);
```

Этот код в итоге выведет

```
<html xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
 <head>
  <style type="text/css"></style> 
 </head>
 <body> 
  <div class="block0"> 
   <div class="pad0"> 
    <div class="fblock"> 
     <div class="block61"> 
      <div class="rpad">
       <h1 class="title">Во Франции по подозрению в планировании теракта задержали двух девушек</h1>
      </div> 
     </div> 
    </div> 
   </div> 
  </div> 
  <div class="block0"> 
   <div class="pad0"> 
    <div class="fblock"> 
     <div class="block61"> 
      <div class="rpad">
       <h1 class="title">Во Фsdfsdfsfх девушек</h1>
      </div> 
     </div> 
    </div> 
   </div> 
  </div>  
 </body>
</html>
```

А без знаний критерий отбора с постоянно разным html, постоянно разным тегом для заголовка с постоянно разной степенью вложенности заголовка с постоянно разным классом (а может и отсутствием оного) у тега с заголовком и вообще каких-либо конкретных критериев поиска - сделать можно только разве что с помощью искусственного интеллекта

Comment: Спасибо.
Попробую ограничить количество сайтов которые будут парситься и  отталкиваться от этого уже.

Comment: @ТоликБугера просто нужно вычленить общий признак у всех них и тогда, возможно, можно будет сделать какой-то алгоритм для всех них